# Lorentz boost tensor notation confusion

Tags: tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry

I have been given this$$
\delta X^{\mu}=\omega_{\mu \nu}\left(M^{\mu \mu}\right)_{\sigma}^{\rho} X^{\sigma}
$$

and I think it should be equal to this but I'm confused if I'm doing it correctly

$$
\delta X^{\mu}=\omega_{\sigma}^{\rho} X^{\sigma}
$$

I just couldn't find a rule in the lowering and upping indices section in the wiki or my Tensor calc book.

Comment: Make sure to define the terms you’re using — without context, it’s unlikely you’ll get a good answer here. However, on a first look, your expression is wrong. Summer indices must appear ones in the lower position and once in the upper position. Furthermore, one side has a $\mu$ as the free index, while the other has $\nu$.

Comment: See this is part of the problem, since the homework is given as $$
\delta X^{\mu}=\omega_{\mu \nu}\left(M^{\mu \mu}\right)_{\sigma}^{\rho} X^{\sigma}
$$ With no further context of what M is. I'm trying to get a Noether current from an action if that helps. I know that typically Poincare transformations look like: $$
\delta X^{\mu}=a_{k}^{\mu} X^{k}
$$

Comment: That equation looks like nonsense to me for the reason noted by @BobKnighton.  Could be that in full context some sense could be made of it though.

Comment: Which book? Which exercise? Try giving the full text of the problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/trUuTW1

Here is the problem, it's his own made up stuff so no book. He makes little mistakes like the one on the bottom. Could this be a mistake?

Comment: Without context I can tell you this: $M$ here represents the generators of the vector representation of the Lorentz group, and $\omega$ is an antisymmetric tensor parametrizing the group elements. The correct expression should be $\delta X^{\mu}=\omega_{\alpha\beta}(M^{\alpha\beta})^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}X^{\nu}$.

Comment: It looks like the problem is fine — the author seems to have just had a stroke while typing this expression.

Comment: Sometimes people are just too distracted, careless, or lazy to get things right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ here represents the generators of the vector representation of the Lorentz group, and $\omega$ is an antisymmetric tensor parametrizing the group elements. In terms of these generators, a Lorentz group element in the vector representation is given by

$$\Lambda=\exp\left(\omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}\right),$$

where it is understood that $\Lambda$ and $M^{\mu\nu}$ are $d\times d$ matrixes in $d$ dimensions.

A finite transformation is given by $X^{\mu}\to\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}X^{\nu}$, which tells us that the infinitesimal transformation law is given by

$$\delta X^{\mu}=\omega_{\alpha\beta}(M^{\alpha\beta})^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}X^{\nu}.$$

For an explicit form of $M$, consult basically any textbook on field theory (for instance, Chapter 3 of Peskin and Schroeder).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a problem in your first formula because as far as *Einstein's Summation Convention* is concerned the symbol:

$$ \omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\mu}$$

is totaly meaningless, because you have sum only with two repeated indices.
Also, poincaré transformations are, in fact, and with more generality:

$$\delta X'^{\mu}= \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} \delta X^{\nu} + a^{\mu}$$